# Add click event to <object> svg

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a problem detecting a click event on a svg that is in

```
    <div class="content svgwrapper">
        <object id="SVGobject" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/MySvg.svg" width="100%" height="400">
                <img src="svg-no.png" alt="No SVG support">
            </object>
    </div>


    document.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('hooray!');
    });
```

Comment: Have you sure you have to add the event listener to the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not better like that?

```js
document.getElementById('SVGobject').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('hooray!');
});
```

```html
<div class="content svgwrapper">
  <object id="SVGobject" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/MySvg.svg" width="100%" height="400">
    <img src="svg-no.png" alt="Click on me!">
  </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as you added this i found this way to do it ty.

Comment: anyway to add it to the documents click event?

Comment: Great! That's why I asked you the question first ;). The question to think about a solution, the answer to confirm this solution ;). Bravo à toi !

Comment: You can attach the (an) event to the body, not to the document itself.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes ;). Try: `getElementByTagName` ;) (of course, the tagname, here, is 'BODY' ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching the click listener to document. You need to attach it to your Object only, for example:

```
document.getElementById("SVGobject").addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('hooray!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach click event to `object` instead of `document`.